# Converting xls file into csv/txt file in Python

Tags: python, csv, graph, xls

I'm Using Python 2.7.3
How can i convert excel file(.xls) to txt/.csv file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
t = []

fig = plt.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')

readFile = open('data.csv', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if plotPair in '. ':
       # skip. or space
       continue
    if idx > 1:  # to skip the first line
        xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        t.append(time_string)
        y.append(float(xAndY[1]))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='blue')
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)

plt.title('IRRADIANCE')
plt.xlabel('TIME')

plt.show()
```

sample of my txt file:

TimeStamp,Irradiance
21/7/2014 0:00,0.66
21/7/2014 0:00,0.71
21/7/2014 0:00,0.65
21/7/2014 0:00,0.67
21/7/2014 0:01,0.58

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the xlrd and csv modules to convert xls to csv.

```
import xlrd
import csv

def xls_to_csv():

    x =  xlrd.open_workbook('data.xls')
    x1 = x.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    csvfile = open('data.csv', 'wb')
    writecsv = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(x1.nrows): #To determine the total rows. 
        writecsv.writerow(x1.row_values(rownum))

    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: how do i put this into my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979344/finding-mode-mean-maximum-in-txt-file-python

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the use of an xls file or a csv file anywhere in that code.

Comment: hi hassaan_w, i have edited my inital question on my top, i think now you can see the csv file

Comment: as my file is a comma separated values i have been using the wrong term of txt file instead of a csv file

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel (r' path your excel file.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet name')
read_file.to_csv (r'Path to store the text file\File name.txt', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Perhaps consider adding an explanation to help describe what the code does.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a windows box or can access a windows box over the network the best solution maybe to write a Python script that uses the subprocess module to launches a vbscript that uses excel to export the file as a CSV file.

```
def doc_count(self, path_and_file):
    print("---- doc_count ----")
    pprint(path_and_file)
    cmd = "cscript.exe word_count.vbs \"" + path_and_file + "\" //NoLogo"
    print(cmd)
    result = subprocess.check_output( cmd, shell=True )
    print(result)
```

The code above is what I use to launch a vbs script to get line and word counts out of MS Word something similar should be possible with excel.