# How to convert XLS to CSV files using python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, xls, qgis

I'm working with python console of `QGIS 2.8.1`. I want to convert many `xls` files into `csv` format using python. My input directory is: `D:\PATRICIA\TESTE\XLS` and output is: `D:\PATRICIA\TESTE\CSV2`.   I wrote this code based in your suggestions ([Converting xls file into csv/txt file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969274/converting-xls-file-into-csv-txt-file-in-python)) and developed it in differente files with different dates `1999/01/2` until `1999/01/31` as: `RR_1999_1_2.xls`, `RR_1999_1_3.xls`, ... `RR_1999_1_31.xls`

I don't know why my script doesn´t works. It means that nothing happened!

**My script is**:

```
import xlrd
import csv
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

#initial and final dates 
data1='19990102'
data2='19990131'

anoi = int(data1[:4])
mesi = int(data1[4:6])
diai = int(data1[6:8])
anof = int(data2[:4])
mesf = int(data2[4:6])
diaf = int(data2[6:8])

start_date = dt.datetime(anoi, mesi, diai)
end_date = dt.datetime(anof, mesf, diaf)

total_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1


for day in xrange(0, total_days):
        current_date = (start_date + dt.timedelta(days = day)).date()
        file_date = str(current_date.year)+'_'+str(current_date.month)+'_'+str(current_date.day)

        srt1='D:/PATRICIA/TESTE/XLS/RR_'+file_date+'.xls'
        srt2='D:/PATRICIA/TESTE/CSV2/RR_'+file_date+'.csv'

        def xls_to_csv():

            x =  xlrd.open_workbook(str1)
            x1 = x.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
            csvfile = open(str2, 'wb')
            writecsv = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

            for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
                writecsv.writerow(x1.row_values(rownum))

            csvfile.close()
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed an important thing, you *declare* the function `xls_to_csv` in a loop, but never call it. The general structure of your script should be:

```
#initializations
data1='19990102'
...
total_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1

# function definition:
def xls_to_csv(str1, str2):
    x =  xlrd.open_workbook(str1)
    x1 = x.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    csvfile = open(str2, 'wb')
    writecsv = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        writecsv.writerow(x1.row_values(rownum))

    csvfile.close()

# loop
for day in xrange(0, total_days):
        current_date = (start_date + dt.timedelta(days = day)).date()
        file_date = str(current_date.year)+'_'+str(current_date.month)+'_'+str(current_date.day)

        srt1='D:/PATRICIA/TESTE/XLS/RR_'+file_date+'.xls'
        srt2='D:/PATRICIA/TESTE/CSV2/RR_'+file_date+'.csv'
        xls_to_csv(srt1, srt2)  # function call
```

Comment: Thanks Serge Ballesta, but appeared this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:/PATRICIA/IG/PYTHON_SCRIPTS/ConvertXlsToCsv.py", line 30, in <module>
    xls_to_csv(srt1, srt2)  # function call
  File "D:/PATRICIA/IG/PYTHON_SCRIPTS/ConvertXlsToCsv.py", line 18, in xls_to_csv
    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
NameError: global name 'sh' is not defined